# Align text to center of text field in double-column in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, alignment, balance

So, I want to achieve this effect, but then automatically (without having to edit the text manually):
[image: alignment]

So basically, the left column has to have a right alignment, and the right column has to have a left alignment. But because it's a double column with 'balance columns' turned on, I don't know how to achieve this. Because when I make two seperate text fields, the 'balance columns' option is gone, right?

So how can I achieve this effect easily without having to manually edit all text?

Thanks :)!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is "automated" enough for your needs, but you could try giving the left-hand column a right-aligned tab, and leaving the right-hand column as is (both columns still technically left-justified):

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't there be some drawbacks with using tabs?

Comment: I don't know enough about your project to say for sure. There could be issues if you tried to resize the text box, or if your lines of text were longer than what's shown in the original post. But if your text (looks to be recipes) remains similar to what you've shown, it can be a good solution. 

On the other hand, you can definitely just use right- and left-justification separately for each column, but I don't know that there's a way to automate that.

Comment: I would be OK with two separate columns, but then I'd somehow have to get the 'balance columns' option in there. Is that possible?

Comment: The balance columns feature is exclusive to an individual text box. However, if you use the method I described, you will still have only one text box, so the balance columns feature should still be available. You'll have to experiment to see if the tabs affect that when adding new text, and/or how  much manual adjustment you'll need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched for this answer for a long time. I have not found an elegant solution.

The best solution I have been able to come up with to semi-automate this is to have separate Text Boxes that I can then apply an Object Style to. Object Styles will allow you to apply a Paragraph Style to all contents in the Text Box. You can set a simple Paragraph Style with right or left justify and then use the Object style to apply that style to the box.

Most times, I just buckle down and do it manually, it's usually faster.

Comment: And by manually, I mean apply the style sheets to the necessary copy one paragraph at a time.

Answer (score 0):

What you want here are tables.

Add a table with 2 columns and however many rows you want – you can do the whole thing with just 2 rows, or keep adding a new row for each line.

You'll need to remove the stroke around the table that appears by default. You can adjust the spacing between cells for your spacing. I've hilighted both in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Put a column break between them, at the bottom of the left column.

Comment: The question is asking how to *automatically* adjust the *alignment*, not the colum breaks